# How is your workflow when you develop a web app in Ubuntu knowing that the font you are using will look different on Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, ubuntu-12.04

I recently started using Ubuntu 12.04 and I found it very cool and easy to use for web development, but I have a problem with FONTS! Why do they look so ugly in Ubuntu?

If you check a website in Firefox Ubuntu and one in Firefox Windows 7 you realize that on Windows looks better every time. Even with ttf-mscorefonts installed will look ugly.

My question is how is your workflow when you develop a web app in Ubuntu knowing that the font you are using will look different on Windows. Do you create a virtual machine with Windows 7 in order to test the fonts at the end of the project?

Many thanks with this
/Blue

Comment: My experience is in contrast with yours. Fonts in firefox Ubuntu looks better than those in Windows 7