# Web development on Linux (Font rendering different from Windows)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, linux, web-applications, ubuntu

I'm doing web development on the Linux OS(Ubuntu,Linux Mint..). Sites look different in Windows and Linux. The font on Firefox in Linux looks smaller/shorter than the font on Firefox in Windows/Mac despite trying to make both fonts exactly the same.

Any of you web developers developing on Linux OS have the same problem? How do you handle it?

I found a question similar to mine, but it's not answered yet. [How is your workflow when you develop a web app in Ubuntu knowing that the font you are using will look different on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300315/how-is-your-workflow-when-you-develop-a-web-app-in-ubuntu-knowing-that-the-font)

Thank you!

Comment: What font family are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Font rendering is different on every single system out there. Even different versions of the same OS can have significant differences in font rendering (including differences in accessibility settings and screen sharpening), not to mention entirely different OSes and entirely different platforms (desktop vs. tablet vs. mobile etc.).

The only way to make sure it looks acceptable on all platforms is to test on as many as possible; **virtual machines** are the de facto tool of choice here. Microsoft offers [free Windows versions](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools) for exactly this purpose to download, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) is a free virtual machine package.

You cannot make it look *identical* on all platforms, but you can make sure it looks acceptable, usable and "native" to a user of the respective platform.